# Kubernetes installation with conjure up

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install kubernetes with conjure-up in my Mac. I installed conjure-up with the help of brew. Once I start conjure-up I am not getting the option to install in localhost. Why is that?

I only see commands requirement as below

```
brew install conjure-up
conjure-up kubernertes
```

[image: Error]

I have tried with all flavours of kubernetes provided by conjure-up and didn't add any add on also.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before using conjure-up on Localhost you need to setup your LXD on local machine. 
As mentioned in [MacOs builds](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/#macos-builds) documentation you need to run:

```
brew install lxc
```

Then you need to run and configure LXD:

```
sudo lxd init
```

Then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I missed the "sudo lxc init" command . I am getting this on running it
Description:
  Create containers from images

Usage:
  lxc init [<remote>:]<image> [<remote>:][<name>] [flags]

Examples:
  lxc init ubuntu:16.04 u1

Localhost is still greyed out or not an option